# git duplex or 2 way merge with save of both merge panels at a time

Tags: git, merge, duplex, winmerge, araxis-merge

The git supports different merge strategies, but nevertheless all these strategies are relied on idea to have has multiple inputs and only a single output. In mine case I want to have 2 outputs of 2 inputs in a single merge.

Why this is important?

Because while I am searching for changes in at least 2 branches, then I do find changes required to be merged simultaneously in both directions. So there is not enough to merge changes from 1-to-2 branch, there is a need to save changes 2-to-1 branch to merge them later. But not Araxis Merge nor Winmerge (or I didn't find it) does not support 2 outputs in a single merge and does not matter how many panels you opened, 2, 3 or even 4. The result of a merge is always be a single output, not a multiple output.

I want a multiple output, to not to search the changes again in a second back merge.

Is there a way to achieve that with the git and using 2- or 3- or 4-panel merge UI?

Comment: What does “duplex” mean in this context?

Comment: @Guildenstern "duplex merge" means 2-way-merge-in-a-single-attempt or 1-to-2 plus 2-to-1 branches merge but in 2 different commits into 2 different branches.